# Twitter java web application is not working in linux ubuntu but it is working in windows why?

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

Twitter java web application is not working in ***Linux ubuntu*** but it is working in ***windows*** why?

Comment: Pretty hard to help diagnose with no information on what the app does, or how it fails on one platform.